# Display Notification Dot But Not Pull Down Notifications

Tags: rooting, lineageos, 8.0-oreo

Is there a way with or without root to display a notification dot for my Messenger(text messaging) app on the home screen but not on the notification dropdown?

Part of this setting is standard for all apps for iOS but the setting "On the lock screen" seems to only be available for certain applications like Gmail and Android Messenger in Android.  Not to mention this doesn't hide the notification on the swipe down notification bar.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the Pixel 2 and Android 9.

Go in your app notifications (facebook messenger in this example) and make sure "Allow notification dot" is ON. Then select which category and in "Behaviour", select "Show silently and minimise".

[image]
[image]

When you get a new message, there will be a dot on the icon (second in the top row) and no notification on lock screen, no notification in top bar with the clock. However, if you drag down the menu, you will see a small notification.

[image]
[image]

Best I could find. Tested with facebook messenger and gmail.

Comment: I believe this only works for some apps at not all but I don't have a Pixel to test this with unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This works for a lot but not all apps.  Download an app called "AutoNotification" in the app store.

Open notification categories.

From there set the app to importance to low priority.

Disable vibrate.

Enable Show Notification Dot.

Disable blink light.

On the lock screen. "Don't show notifications at all."